# Multiple Search Input's Using `this` for Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am wanting to achieve is having multiple search forms throught my website without having to call a seperate `selector` for each one. I've tried messing around with `this` to get the current value and use that on keydown but anytime I submit the search the only value I get is `[object Object]`. What am I doing wrong here?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="fa fa-search pull-left"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control SearchInput" name="search" placeholder="Search for your products!" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            <span>Translate my search</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.SearchInput').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';
            var search = $(this).find($('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value'));
            if (search) {
                url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
            }
            var search_directly = $("select[name='search_directly']").val();
            if (search_directly == 1) {
                url += '&search_directly=1';
            }
            location = url;
        }
    })
```

Comment: If you want to use `this` and you are already bound to the input then you can simply do: `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is this line:

```
$('.SearchInput').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // ...

    // here, `this` is already your input, no need to call .find()
    var search = $(this).find($('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value'));

    // ...
```

You are binding the keydown listener on all elements with the class `SearchInput`, which are your `<input>` elements. This means that, within your event handler, `this` will refer to the current `<input>` on which the event `keydown` happened. Where you are going wrong is calling [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on your current `<input>` element (i.e. `this`) which searches for other `<input>` elements inside of it, and those do not exist.

This is how that line should look:

```
var search = $(this).attr('value');
```

Or even shorter, you can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var search = $(this).val();
```

Comment: That makes total since overlooked that i put that on the input itself. However if i try using the code provided I'm getting `Exception: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

Comment: Or just  `var search = $(this).val();`

Comment: @DelightedD0D way ahead of you :P

Comment: Lol, yeah just saw that :)

Comment: Ha. Way ahead of both of you. Where is the love? :D

Comment: Works like a charm sorry @JasonCust, nem035 goes a bit more in depth with his answer :x

Comment: @NooBskie Hahaha. No worries. It was a joke for Delighted and Nem patting each other on the back. I saw that Nem had already explained it so my answer was simply a demo of my original comment on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based off my comment, here is an example using some of your code:

```js
$('.SearchInput').bind('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var search = $(this).val();
    console.log(search);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="fa fa-search pull-left"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control SearchInput" name="search" placeholder="Search for your products!" value="" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span>Translate my search</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```